# How to change the color of Listitems in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am just trying to change the background color of all the List items in Jquery mobile on a button click by adding a css class to the list items but its not working here is the fiddle of my work kindly help me to fix this issue.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DineshRaja/wef4wp4e/)

```
function changeListBackground(){
    $("#sampleList li").addClass("selectedli");
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle works, if you change the javascript option  "Load Type" to "no wrap - <head>"

Comment: Tried this but still it didn't work @Ridrog :(

Answer (score 0):

The only code you have on JSFiddle is the button? No CSS?
Ensure that the div which the button is located in has the id "sampleList".

You should remove the current class when adding a new class, Also I presume the new css you wish to use is located in a css file and it targets the class "selected li".

**You should only switch classes to add or remove functionality**, you can use the built in functions of jQuery to do the following.

```
    $("#sampleList li").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

or for multiple styles use

```
    $("#sampleList li").css({"background-color": "yellow", "font-size": "200%"});
```

You should probably read a book or 2 about how to use jQuery if you wish to use it successfully.

Sean

Comment: Now I have updated the fiddle sorry I forgot to apply the changes in fiddle and I am in need of adding that class because I will make some processing based on the Listitems with that class

Comment: I think it's a bad advice to change css properties inside of your javascript. It's a mess if you want to change more then one property and it's much more semantic to write `.addClass("error")` then `.css("background-color": "red")` It's also easier to add/remove properties and you can reuse the class for another thing inside your project.

Comment: Yes I agree if you needed to change multiple styles, adding a class would be much easier, @Dinesh's function name was changeListBackground() - so I assumed it was just one style that he need to change. It's better to inline the style if its just one change, especially if your using jQuery, tis the reason they added the function lol, I can't give a good example using fsFiddle as it just doesn't work when you try call a js function with a onclick();

Comment: Just use the latest version of jQuery and read up on the addClass function, If you add your code into notepad++ for example you'll see realistic view of what it will all look like on the server rather than when you use fsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AlphaDogg marking it as fixed :) and yes Fiddle is having some difference than the actual output will use Notepad++ or Sublime.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue by making the following change

```
$("#sampleList").find("li").removeClass("selectedli").addClass("selectedli");
```

It's working for me in the app but not in the Fiddle anyway this helped me alot.